# Collections of classes in VBA

Tags: object-oriented, vba

I have noticed this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49389392/nested-classes-and-collections-vba in StackOverflow, but it got closed faster than I could have answered. However, it was concerning a best practice for usage of collections of classes.

I usually use `Array` and I add to it like this:

```
Public Sub AddToTeam(emp As Employee)

    Dim cnt As Long
    cnt = UBound(pTeam)

    If Not pTeam(0) Is Nothing Then
        ReDim Preserve pTeam(cnt + 1)
        cnt = cnt + 1
    End If
    Set pTeam(cnt) = emp

End Sub
```

Furthermore, I initialize the Array like this in the class:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ReDim pTeam(0)
End Sub
```

---

This is the working code, feel free to give any ideas:

**Main Module**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim EmpA    As New Employee
    Dim EmpB    As New Employee
    Dim ManA    As New Employee
    Dim TeamA   As New Team

    ManA.Name = "John Doe Top Manager"
    EmpA.Name = "Peter"
    EmpB.Name = "George"

    Set EmpB.Manager = ManA
    TeamA.Name = "The best team!"

    TeamA.AddToTeam ManA
    TeamA.AddToTeam EmpA
    TeamA.AddToTeam EmpB

    TeamA.PrintNames
    Debug.Print TeamA.Name
    TeamA.PrintInfoForManagers

End Sub
```

**Class Employee**

```
Option Explicit

Private pName           As String
Private pManager        As Employee
Private pAge            As Long
Private pTeam           As String
Private pHasManager     As Boolean

Public Property Get HasManager() As Boolean
    HasManager = pHasManager
End Property

Public Property Let HasManager(Value As Boolean)
    pHasManager = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Manager() As Employee
    Set Manager = pManager
End Property

Public Property Set Manager(Value As Employee)
    Set pManager = Value
    HasManager = True
End Property

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pName
End Property

Public Property Let Name(Value As String)
    pName = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Team() As Employee
    Team = pTeam
End Property

Public Property Let Team(Value As Employee)
    pTeam = Value
End Property
```

**Class Team**

```
Option Explicit

Private pTeam()         As Employee
Private pName           As String

Public Sub PrintInfoForManagers()

    Dim emp As Variant
    For Each emp In pTeam
        If emp.HasManager Then
            Debug.Print emp.Name & " is managed by " & emp.Manager.Name
        Else
            Debug.Print emp.Name & " has no manager."
        End If
    Next emp

End Sub

Public Sub PrintNames()

    Dim emp As Variant
    For Each emp In pTeam
        Debug.Print emp.Name
    Next emp

End Sub

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pName
End Property

Public Property Let Name(Value As String)
    pName = Value
End Property

Public Sub AddToTeam(emp As Employee)

    Dim cnt As Long
    cnt = UBound(pTeam)

    If Not pTeam(0) Is Nothing Then
        ReDim Preserve pTeam(cnt + 1)
        cnt = cnt + 1
    End If
    Set pTeam(cnt) = emp

End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ReDim pTeam(0)
End Sub
```

---

So how would you review/improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer not to initiate arrays until they're needed.  Automatically initiating your array can make it difficult to determine whether the array has been used.  Using the `Team` class as an example, calling `PrintNames` before any names are added will throw an error.

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ReDim pTeam(0)
End Sub
```

The main reason this is done is to avoid throwing an error when checking to whether or not an array has been initialized.

There is a trick to avoid the error 9, `Subscript out of range`. Checking to see if an array `IsEmpty()` on an uninitialized array will cause `UBound()` to return -1.

By using `Call IsEmpty(pTeam)` instead of `ReDim pTeam(0)` we can easily check whether the array has actually been used using `If UBound(pTeam) = -1 Then`.

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Call IsEmpty(pTeam)
End Sub

Public Sub AddToTeam(emp As Employee)
    If UBound(pTeam) = -1 Then
        ReDim pTeam(0)
    Else
        ReDim Preserve pTeam(UBound(pTeam) + 1)
    End If
    Set pTeam(UBound(pTeam)) = emp
End Sub
```

Alternatively, we could write a function to check if the array has been used.

```
Public Function hasMembers()
    Call IsEmpty(pTeam)
    hasMembers = UBound(pTeam) > -1
End Function
```

### Using a Private Type to Reference Class Members

Mathieu Guindon (formally known as Mat's Mug) likes to use a User Defined Type (UDT) named `This` to reference class level variables.  I have adopted the technique but name it `vars` instead of `This`.   In this way you can avoid having to the class variable names different from the parameter names (see code below).

### Refactored Code

**Employee:Class**

```
Option Explicit

Private Type Variables
    Name As String
    Manager As Employee
    Age As Long
    Team As String
End Type

Private vars As Variables

Public Function HasManager() As Boolean
    HasManager = Not vars.Manager Is Nothing
End Function

Public Property Get Manager() As Employee
    Set Manager = vars.Manager
End Property

Public Property Set Manager(Value As Employee)
    Set vars.Manager = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = vars.Name
End Property

Public Property Let Name(Value As String)
    vars.Name = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Team() As Employee
    Team = vars.Team
End Property

Public Property Let Team(Value As Employee)
    vars.Team = Value
End Property

Public Function This() As Team
    Set This = Me
End Function
```

**Team:Class**

```
Option Explicit

Private Type Variables
    Team() As Employee
    Name As String
End Type
Private vars As Variables

Public Sub PrintInfoForManagers()

    Dim emp As Variant
    For Each emp In vars.Team
        If emp.HasManager Then
            Debug.Print emp.Name & " is managed by " & emp.Manager.Name
        Else
            Debug.Print emp.Name & " has no manager."
        End If
    Next emp

End Sub

Public Sub PrintNames()
    Dim emp As Variant
    If UBound(vars.Team) = -1 Then
        Debug.Print "There are no Names to Print"
    Else
        For Each emp In vars.Team
            Debug.Print emp.Name
        Next emp
    End If

End Sub

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = vars.Name
End Property

Public Property Let Name(Value As String)
    vars.Name = Value
End Property

Public Sub AddToTeam(emp As Employee)
    If Not Me.hasMembers Then
        ReDim vars.Team(0)
    Else
        ReDim Preserve vars.Team(UBound(vars.Team) + 1)
    End If
    Set vars.Team(UBound(vars.Team)) = emp
End Sub

Public Function hasMembers()
    Call IsEmpty(vars.Team)
    hasMembers = UBound(vars.Team) > -1
End Function

Public Function This() As Team
    Set This = Me
End Function
```

Comment: Interesting ideas, thanks, `Class_Initialize` really somehow smells. 
In general, why are you using `Call`? I thought this was one of the "forbidden" VBA features, just like `Integer`. A separate *Thumbs Up* for the Enums. It looks a bit clearer than the automatic `pVariable` from MZ-Code.

Comment: `Call IsEmpty (vars.Team)` looks more natural then `IsEmpty vars.Team`  to me.  Although there is no speed advantage to using `Integer` instead of `Long`, I would not call  `Integer` a "forbidden" fracture. You mean  `User Defined Types`not `Enums`  but thanks!

Comment: Yup, I meant `User Defined Types`. :)

Comment: This is gold - There is a trick to avoid the error 9, Subscript out of range. Checking to see if an array IsEmpty() on an uninitialized array will cause UBound() to return -1.   My vote of: `abs(UBound(vars.Team))`

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the need for the `HasManager` property. Either a `Manager` is assigned, or not. It wouldn't make sense for you to set it to True when there isn't one, or False when there is.

Then just change your `Print` function to check -

```
If Not emp.Manager Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print emp.Name & " is managed by " & emp.Manager.Name
 Else
    Debug.Print emp.Name & " has no manager."
```

If it was easy to overload the class initialization for employee, I'd say make a name value obligatory, but it's really not a simple task in VBA.

---

These two properties:

> ```
> Public Property Get Team() As Employee
>     Team = pTeam
> End Property
>
> Public Property Let Team(Value As Employee)
>     pTeam = Value
> End Property
> ```

Are passing `Objects` - why not pass `Strings` given the team information is handled by a string.

Comment: Both are good ideas, thanks. However, I like the `HasManager`, it somehow gives me some kind of an interface to work with. `Not Is Nothing` is a good way around. `Team` is assigned as employee, because I can use some other properties later (probably).

Comment: Passing string `Names` for the managers instead of `Employee` objects defeats the purpose of the post.  Consider that you add and email field to the `Employee` class and needed to retrieve the Email address of an employees manager.  Currently you could simply use `Employee.Manager.Email `.  If you use string then you would have to iterate over all the managers  to find the Email address.